# Batch: How to take input from file and assign to variable in batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I have to read contents from a file. In this case, Files.txt. The script is as below:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
REM for /F "delims=" %%b in (Files.txt) do @set str1=%%b
REM set str1=bcd
for /F "delims=" %%a in (Files.txt) do (
    set str1=%%a
    if not x%str1:bcd=%==x%str1% (
        echo OK
    ) else (
        echo Not OK
    )
)
endlocal
```

When I assign value of str1 manually, it executes fine but while taking from file which contains multiple values like aer,bcd,123 etc. It fails.

Am I doing any mistake in this script?

Comment: Use `if not "!str1:bcd=!"=="!str1!"`. Read http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve -
Based on what I have done before - I tend to make sure I break things up.
 - http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ has a great site on Batch files.
I would make sure you use tokens which will get you where you want to go i.e. columns of data

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%G IN (Files.txt) DO call:WORK %%G %%H

:WORK
SET aer=%1
SET bcd=%2
```